# How do you install Next.js on shared host with cPanel/SSH?

Tags: node.js, next.js, cpanel, shared-hosting, litespeed

I have installed a Node.js app using cPanel, and that seems to work fine - but how do you install for example Next.js, when npm/npx doesn't work in SSH?

Usually I would just run npx create-next-app, at least locally this works fine.

Am I wrong to use a shared host with LiteSpeed/cPanel? I see the Next.js documentation strongly recommends using their own Vercel platform, but I would rather use whatever I'm used to - assuming that is possible.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Use a VPS and make your life easier if you are using nextjs. Vercel free tier is very slow to be honest. Haven't used the paid one.

Comment: I think the best way you should make the project on your local, and upload it to git then pull the repository on VPS, it's should work well.